# Find the missing constant in the PDF $f(t) = ct^{-0.5}, 0< t\leq 1$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

is it possible for someone to explain me [the following problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8Cnr.png)?

> 4. Let the delay for a computer packets in the internet be modelled by T, which has the density function
>      $$f(t) = \begin{cases}
>    ct^{-0.5}, & 0< t\leq 1 \\
>    0, & \text{otherwize.}
>    \end{cases}$$
>      [sic]

a) Find the constant $c$

I have solved questions before using the fact that when I integrate a PDF over $(-\infty,\infty)$, it provides a value of $1$. So I integrate the pdf $f(t)$, then equate the result to $1$ to solve for $c$. However, the answer sheet tells me that $c = 0.5$, while I keep getting a value of $c=0.707$. Can anyone point out where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Please use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and show your work. Also, please type out images.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\int_0^1ct^{-1/2}dt = \left[2ct^{1/2}\right]_{t=0}^1=2c=1\\
\iff 
c=1/2
$$

Answer (score 0):

You have the correct idea; the integral of the function over its range should be 1:

$ \int_0^1 ct^{-.5} dt = 1 $

I did this on paper and I get the answer sheet's result, 0.5; my guess is that you are evaluating the integral incorrectly. What do you get as the antiderivative of the function?